# XML method documentation does not produce a warning when a parameter name doesn't match

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

In VB I will get a warning if a method parameter name does not match the XML documentation:

[image]

> XML comment parameter 'arg' does not match a parameter on the
>   corresponding 'sub' statement. XML comment will be ignored.

In C#, I don't get a warning:

[image]

I know if I did things right and renamed the argument using the "refactor" context menu, it would have renamed the XML doc as well, but let's assume I don't always do things the right way.

Why does this happen?  Is there a setting I can switch on to get these warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable XML documentation file in your project's properties:

[image]

You will get warnings:

[image]

Comment: Great!  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)